# Collapsible list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, collapsable

```
    <script>   
     $(document).ready(function(){
           var xml = "<root> \
                <method name='A'> \
                <childcall name='B'></childcall> \
                <childcall name='C'></childcall> \
                </method> \
                <method name='B'> \
                <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
                </method> \
                <method name='C'> \
                <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
                <childcall name='E'></childcall> \
                </method> \
                </root>";

            var data = $.parseXML(xml);
            console.log(data);
            $(data).find('method').each(function(){
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){
                    name = $(this).attr('name');
                    $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                });
             });
      });

      </script>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap"></div>
</body>
```

The above code traverses the xml and prints items as - A B C B D C D E.
I want to make this a collapsible list, like in the given link: http://www.sendesignz.com/index.php/jquery/77-how-to-create-expand-and-collapse-list-item-using-jquery

Any hint on how to make it collapsible?

EDIT: Thanks for help. Sorry I cannot accept more than one answer as correct. So Shikiryu solution is also correct.

Comment: So...what's wrong with the code in the article you linked? Doesn't it work in your case?

Comment: Is the first `</script>` normal ?

Comment: Corrected the <script> tag. Since I am generating the html inside JQuery, not sure how to apply the collapsible javascript to the generated html. Need a little help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to print exactly like given in the link

1. edit your js code to out put html like this

   ```
    <ul>
        <li class="category">Menu 1
            <ul>
                <li>Menu 1 sub 1</li>
                <li>Menu 2 sub 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
    </ul>
   ```
2. Us the provided JS code

   ```
    $('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
    $('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
    $('li.category').children().hide();
    $('li.category').each(
        function(column) {
            $(this).click(function(event){
                if (this == event.target) {
                    if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
                        $(this).children().show();
                        $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
                        $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $(this).children().hide();
                        $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
                        $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
                      }
                  }
              });
         }
    );
   ```

**UPDATE1 : Try this JS code it will print the result as I wrote in the point number one**
**NOTE : the code is not optimized **

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       var xml = "<root> \
            <method name='A'> \
            <childcall name='B'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='C'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='B'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='C'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='E'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            </root>";

        var data = $.parseXML(xml);
        console.log(data);

        var htmltxt="test<ul>";
        $(data).find('method').each(function(){
            var namenode = $(this).attr('name');
            var count = 0;
            $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){ count++; });
            if(count>0){
                htmltxt = htmltxt + "<li='category'>" + namenode +"<ul>";
                $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){ 
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        htmltxt = htmltxt + "<li>" + name + "</li>";    
                });
                htmltxt = htmltxt + "</ul></li>";
            }else{
                htmltxt = htmltxt +"<li>"+namenode+"</li>";
            }
         });
        htmltxt = htmltxt + "</ul>";
        $("#page-wrap").html(htmltxt);
  });
```

**UPDATE 2 JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/faraqsa/CKa6V/

Comment: `var count = 0;
            $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){ count++; });
            if(count>0){` this instead of `$(this).children('childcall').length >0` is a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, you need to generate the same HTML as that example (using ul and li instead of div)

```
$(data).find('method').each(function(){
    var hasChild = $(this).children('childcall').length > 0;
    curLi += '<li';
    curLi += ((hasChild) ? ' class="category plusimageapply">': '>');
    curLi += $(this).attr('name');
    if(hasChild){
        curLi += '<ul>';
         $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){
             var name = $(this).attr('name');
             curLi += '<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a></li>';
         });
        curLi += '</ul>';
    }
    curLi += '</li>';
 });
$('#test').append(curLi);
```

*Note that it can be optimized.*

**Then**, you need to indicate some CSS (hide children, adding + and - etc)

```
.category ul{display:none;}
```

**Finally**, you need to apply their JS

```
$('li.category').click(function(event){
    if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
        $(this).children().show();
        $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().hide();
        $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
    }
});
```

That gives : http://jsfiddle.net/dujRe/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery's toggle effect, it goes something like this:

```
$("#CollapseTrigger").click(function () {
    $("#ListToBeHidden").toggle("slow");
});
```