# Traverse xml recursively with JQuery

Tags: jquery, recursion, xml-parsing

```
    <div id="page-wrap"></div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
       var xml = "<root> \
            <method name='A'> \
            <childcall name='B'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='C'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='B'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='C'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='E'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='D'> \
            <childcall name='F'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            </root>";

        var data = $.parseXML(xml);
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data);

        var htmltxt="<ul>";
        $(data).find('method').each(traverseXml);
        htmltxt = htmltxt + "</ul>";
        //alert(htmltxt);
        $("#page-wrap").html(htmltxt);

     function traverseXml(data){
            var namenode = $(this).attr('name');
            var count = 0;
            $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){ count++; });
            if(count>0){
                htmltxt = htmltxt + "<li class='category'>" + namenode +"<ul>";

                $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){ 
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        htmltxt = htmltxt + "<li>" + name + "</li>";    
                });
                htmltxt = htmltxt + "</ul></li>";
            }else{
                htmltxt = htmltxt +"<li>"+namenode+"</li>";
            }
         }




$('li.category').addClass('plusimageapply');
$('li.category').children().addClass('selectedimage');
$('li.category').children().hide();
$('li.category').each(
function(column) {
$(this).click(function(event){
if (this == event.target) {
if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
$(this).children().show();
$(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
$(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
}
else
{
$(this).children().hide();
$(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
$(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
}
}
});
}
);
  });
```

The code traverses the one level of xml. Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/CKa6V/10/

I am looking to traverse the xml nodes recursively such that every node expands to the last child. For e.g. A expands to B, B then becomes expandable and expands to D and finally D expands to F. Similarly for all nodes.

EDIT: Sorry if the question was not clear. I am looking for the following output-

```
A
|__B
   |__D
      |__F
|__C
   |__D
      |__F
   |__E
B
|__D
   |__F
C
|__D
   |__F
|__E

D
|__F
```

Comment: what is the question ? What isn't working? When clcik on visible elements, children are diplayed

Comment: are node names the same on all levels? Have you looked through the numerous other posts on site that do same thing such as in links on right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with [the code I've done on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15925282/460368) and modify it as below (link to the new fiddle in the end of this answer) :

JS :

```
var xml = "<root> \
            <method name='A'> \
            <childcall name='B'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='C'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='B'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            <method name='C'> \
            <childcall name='D'></childcall> \
            <childcall name='E'></childcall> \
            </method> \
            </root>";

        var data = $.parseXML(xml);
        console.log(data);
        var curLi = [];
        $(data).find('method').each(function(){
            var hasChild = $(this).children('childcall').length > 0;
            curLi.push('<li');
            curLi.push(((hasChild) ? ' class="category plusimageapply">': '>'));
            curLi.push($(this).attr('name'));
            if(hasChild){
                curLi.push('<ul>');
                 $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){
                     var name = $(this).attr('name');
                     curLi.push('<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a></li>');
                 });
                curLi.push('</ul>');
            }
            curLi.push('</li>');
         });
        $('#test').append(curLi.join(''));

$('li.category').click(function(event){
    if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
        $(this).children().show();
        $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().hide();
        $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
    }
});
```

HTML :

```
<ul id="test">

</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dujRe/9/

---

### EDIT

Alright, I thought you were talking about physical expansion - as every child must be displayed.

For your tree you can do this :

JS :

```
var data = $.parseXML(xml);
var curLi = [];
function parseBranch(l){
    var b = $(data).find('method[name='+l+']');
    if(b.length > 0){
        curLi.push('<ul>');
    }
    b.each(function(){
        $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            curLi.push('<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a>');
            parseBranch(name); // recursion here
            curLi.push('</li>');
        });
    });
    if(b.length > 0){
        curLi.push('</ul>');
    }
}
$(data).find('method').each(function(){
    var hasChild = $(this).children('childcall').length > 0;
    curLi.push('<li');
    curLi.push(((hasChild) ? ' class="category plusimageapply">': '>'));
    curLi.push($(this).attr('name'));
    if(hasChild){
        curLi.push('<ul>');
        $(this).children('childcall').each(function(){
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            curLi.push('<li><a href="'+name+'">'+name+'</a>');
            parseBranch(name);
            curLi.push('</li>');
        });
        curLi.push('</ul>');
    }
    curLi.push('</li>');
});
$('#test').append(curLi.join(''));

$('li.category').click(function(event){
    if($(this).is('.plusimageapply')) {
        $(this).children().show();
        $(this).removeClass('plusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('minusimageapply');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).children().hide();
        $(this).removeClass('minusimageapply');
        $(this).addClass('plusimageapply');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dujRe/10/

Comment: hi Shikiryu, but this code does not expand that way I have specified in the output. The expansion should go down to the last child. I suppose it would require recursive code. Since I am new to JQuery I am  finding it bit difficult to get the code in place.

Comment: @user32262 I think I didn't understand what you meant about "expand". Now I think I got it ;)

Comment: Thanks Shikiryu. The expansion is correct now. But initially all parent nodes must be collapsed. And one click should expand one level down. So, click on A should show B and C, then click on B should show D and the click on D should show F. So expanding one node in one click. And I don't need the hrefs anyway. I also came up with a recursive solution but haven't got the display and expansion working. Maybe I ll post that. Eventually I will accept your answer.